# How to divide a data.frame into seversal data.frames according to the first row numer? or divide data.frame when the number is not ascending

Tags: r

```
df <- tibble(NumberA = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,1,2),NumberB = c(2,3,4,3,3,1,2,3,2,2,1))
```

original data:
[image: original data]

divided data:
[image: divided data]

Then, calculate: mean(abs(the column of Number B minus the column of Number A)))

Comment: Most likely this post is a duplicate, try: `split(df, cumsum(df$NumberA == 1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
split(df, cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(df$NumberA) < 0)))
# $`0`
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   NumberA NumberB
#     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1       1       2
# 2       2       3
# 3       3       4
# 4       4       3
# 5       5       3
# $`1`
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   NumberA NumberB
#     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1       1       1
# 2       2       2
# 3       3       3
# 4       4       2
# $`2`
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   NumberA NumberB
#     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1       1       2
# 2       2       1
```

Comment: Same story......

Comment: split(df, cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(df$NumberA) < = 0)))

Comment: @zx8754 same reply. I have no issue with marking it as duplicate, in fact I support it. The premise of duplicates is strong, but sometimes new users don't know how to adapt the other question's answer(s) to their particular question. It's not hard to justify this difficulty as "growing pains", I think saying it's a dupe and then how to apply that to their details are both relevant. While I agree that it would be better if I found the dupe first, sometimes it's much easier to just dump some code quickly and label as dupe second. Thanks for your diligence, don't judge me please.